# El reporte solo me imprime lo que se muestra en la tabla

Tags: php

Buenas tengo un sistema con php donde selecciono multiples checkboxs, y tengo que seleccionarlos para despues hacer reporte donde llama el value de los chekboxes. 
Mi problema es que cuando busco n-clientes y los selecciono, aunque esten en checked todos los seleccionados, a la hora de hacer mi reporte, solo me recoge los que se me muestra en la pantalla.

Ejemplo : 
  Si en la 1°ra pagina seleccione 2 y en la 2°Pagina seleccione 4.
   Solo me recoge los datos de los que estan seleccionados en la pagina que se MUESTRA visualmente en mi tabla y no los otros que busque y seleccione.

Alguna idea o ayuda que me puedan aportar para que se guarden en 2do plano los checkboxes?.

Comment: ¿Cuando cambias de páginas se recarga el navegador, o es tipo pestañas que se muestran u ocultan con javascript?

Comment: Se recarga le navegador, a la hora de buscar, es una tabla fija sin paginacion que se puede escoger la cantidad de registors que se quiera.
Pero a la hora de buscar y que me salga el que busco y le doy checked, aunque se guarde en el localstore, a la hora de imprimir solo me jala los que me veo en la tabla checkeados.

Comment: Puedes mandar más información y código?

Answer (score 0):

Debes ir almacenando los datos seleccionados antes de pasar a la selección de la segunda página y que vuelva a cargarse el navegador.
La opción más práctica es ahcerlo dentro de la variable global $_SESSION para la que tendrás de usar la función session_start() para comenzar y session_destroy() para eliminar todos los datos guardados.